# Sqlalchemy: Why does querying with a string primary key work for an primary key of type integer?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, primary-key

My model is defined so that the primary key is an integer

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
   email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
   password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

Both of these return a user correctly:

```
User.query.get("1")
User.query.get(1)
```

Why am I able to use a string to query an integer column?
From the docs: A scalar, tuple, or dictionary representing the primary key. -> does string count
as a scalar? I'm not sure what scalar means in this context.

I am using a MySql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes mysql automatically, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers as necessary, and vice versa.